# Square wave DFT in PNg

Tags: java, image, matlab, compression, dft

So a bit more details:
I'm starting to write my "bachelor's degree thesis "
And it's gonna be something be something related to image compression

I was  wondering do you know about any attempts to use a square wave fourier series (transformation) in the PNG format as filter instead of the haar wavelet? Would it be any good ?

If you have any other ideas what I could do my paper about , it would help.
My timeframe is from now till May- June

Answer (score 0):

proving that lu decomposition is a singular matrix.

Comment: creating a database of the square wave fourier series and writing a visual basic program

Comment: with line 8 that reads like this 'end PNG console.writeline (''hello world'') and line 20 that reads like this 'end filter

Comment: it would be good to use instead of the haar wavelet.